# Assigning setState to variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've got a page displaying a bunch of widgets. All of them are separated from each other and I'd need to update the UI. For this, I use `StatefulBuilder` and it works fine but the problem is that I need to pass the `setState` between them since I need to modify different widgets (like for example the header actions).

So I thought that moving all of these `StatefulBuilders` from them (I have one for each) and creating a global one would help. And it does, but still, need to pass the `setState` to the children widgets.

Is there any way to assign the `setState` to a global var like this?

```
var _setState = null;

class NewSetPage extends StatelessWidget {    
  @override
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, setState) {
        setState(() {
          _setState = setState;
        });
        return Scaffold(
        ...
```

Inside my widgets, I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
_setState(() {
   _setState = setState;
});
```

It doesn't throw any error tho.

Comment: if you are creating a `stateless` widget with the first child as a `stateful builder`, it is the same as creating a `stateful` widget. you might as well convert your widget to `stateful` and remove the stateful builder. for the sake of simplicity

Comment: I rarely need to update a page that much so all my widgets are `stateless` with some `StatefulBuilder` on them. I find this much simpler to read/understand. But you're probably right, maybe for this scenario is worth having a full `statefull` widget instead

Comment: I agree with you. I would use `stateful builder` only in case if I need to update a small portion of my `stateless` widget within the change events from inside of that particular portion. However, I would suggest never storing the state/stateSetter/context as a global variable as it messes up with the regular flow of flutter's working.

Comment: ok, so better passing the value all the time to the children widgets then

Comment: yep, always pass values down. if you fill you can make an object for passing as a collection of those values...

Comment: Feel free to add that answer

Comment: thanks. If you have any doubt let me know. I'll try to help you out if I can.

Comment: no, don't worry, but move your comment to a proper answer and I'll accept it closing this as well

Comment: sure, I'll do it asap

Comment: Done, thanks for being a good sport. We need people like you here. Have a good day.

Comment: thanks mate, same for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a `stateless` widget with the first child as a `stateful builder`, it is the same as creating a `stateful widget`.

You might as well convert your widget to `stateful` one and remove the `stateful builder`, just for the sake of simplicity

I would use `stateful builder` only in case **if I need to update a small portion of my stateless widget**, while the change events originating from inside of that particular portion.

> Is there any way to assign the setState to a global var like this?

I would suggest **never** storing the state/stateSetter/context as a global variables as it messes up with the regular flow of flutter.